# Hide/disable the PowerApps button from the hero bar

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I want to hide the ***PowerApps*** button from the Hero bar.
I tried the below PowerShell approaches:

**Approach 1**:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url "Site URL" –Credentials (Get-Credential)
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$ctx.Site.DisableAppViews = $true;
$ctx.Site.DisableFlows = $true;
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Approach 2**:

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity "Site URL" -DisableFlows 1 -DisableAppViews 1
```

Using the above, I am able to hide the ***Power Automate*** button but not the ***PowerApps***.

How can I hide the ***PowerApps*** button?

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported to hide the PowerApps button from list menu.

The parameter `DisableAppViews` hides only “**See all apps**” option. The “**Custom forms**” button is not possible to hide (while keeping the PowerApps function) using OOB solution for the time being.

See a UserVoice post here: [Option to disable Flow and PowerApps.](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/15619065-option-to-disable-flow-and-powerapps)

Answer (score 0):

You can now hide **Power Apps** option from list/library command bar at the top using JSON formatting.

Use JSON like below in view formatting option:

```
{
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "powerApps",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Documentation**: [Command bar customization syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)